# RequestMapping canot be access by the navigator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and i try to display a get request.  I'm using 2 classes: `Greeting.java` and `GreetingController`:

```
    package greeting;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

My controller is GreetingController.java :

```
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello ,%s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter  = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name",defaultValue = "World")String name){
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),String.format(template,name));
    }
}
```

And when i insert this url (`http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=gabriel`) I get this error on the navigator :

```
  Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 10 19:35:17 CET 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I not understand why he not found the page.
if a people can help me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping `/greeting` exists but an error occurred causing a redirect to the location `/error` which has not been configured